# R - How to use apply instead of for loop in regex matches

Tags: regex, r, for-loop, apply

I have a for loop in which I extract the file names in the urls and then download and save the files:

```
for(url in filing.urls) {
    m = regexpr("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+\\.txt",url,perl=T)
    file.name = regmatches(url,m)
    download.file(url, destfile=paste("filings/",file.name, sep=""), method="curl")
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to build all the `file.names` in a single line using apply? It might make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if `filing.urls` is a vector:

```
f <- function(url)
  regmatches(url, regexpr("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+\\.txt",url,perl=T))
file.names <- sapply(filin.urls, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is at least one character before the first digit this seems simpler:

```
lapply(filing.urls, function(url) 
           download.file(url, 
                destfile = sub("(.*\\D)\\d+-\\d+-\\d+\\.txt", "filings/", url),
                method = "curl"
           )
)
```